# string format money ,

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion, currency

I need to convert that number 1600000 in this format 1,600,000.00

I tried this code:

```
string number= string.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToDecimal(suma));
txtMontoTproyeccion.Text = number;
```

but the point should be in the decimal place.

Comment: What is your current output? Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: What are you seeing? What locale/culture are you running in?